# Exception thrown by `Insert all` RDF triples in Oracle11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, rdf, oracle-spatial

After creating a new table containing rdf data

```
create table rdf_data (triple SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S);
execute SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('mymodel', 'rdf_data', 'triple');
```

I am trying to add multiple RDF triples at once

```
insert all 
into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar'))
into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', 'bar', 'foo', 'foobar')) 
select 1 from dual;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-00932:  inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Instead, the following examples works:

```
-- Trying insert all with integers
create table foo(a integer);
insert all 
into foo values (1) 
into foo values (2) 
select 1 from dual;

-- Inserting a single RDF triple
insert into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar'));
```

However, given a table of 1,000,000 tuples I need to perform many inserts for each tuple (for instance, one insert for each table attribute). I suppose that having multiple insertions is not a viable solution.

```
create table bar(id varchar(100), foo char(100), foobar char(100));
insert all
into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<rdfs:type>', '<myont:Bar>'))
into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFoo>', foo))
into rdf_data(triple) 
values (sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFooBar>', foobar)) 
into rdf_data(triple) values (...)
select * from bar;
```

Is there any known bug within the insertion of multiple triples with `insert all`?

Comment: Is your `sdo_rdf_triple_s` type the same as the one defined at http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/rdf-overview.htm#RDFRM-GUID-D7734D1A-EAC0-4581-B3CC-2E23C8F97D94%22? That appears to consist of five numbers, not four strings as in your example.

Comment: The use of SDO_TRIPLE_S is correct as used. The internal content of that type is a set of 5 numbers indeed, but the most common constructor takes four strings (and constructs the actual object with five numbers). The numbers inside the object point to the actual string values, kept in (internal) table MDSYS.RDF_VALUE$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could say it is a bug. Or at least a limitation when dealing with the SDO_TRIPLE_S object type ...

Then again, why not use multiple inserts ?

**EDIT 1: based on clarifications by the OP.**

So the actual need is to generate multiple triples from a single input row. Sorry for missing that from the original question. That is definitely an appropriate use for the multi-insert statement. Unfortunately, that does not seem to work when the value list contains an SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S object. The restriction is not with all objects (other object types work fine).

But then the SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S constructor does extensive work in checking the physical triple store for existing values. I imagine that this is what causes trouble ...

**EDIT 2: The original INSERT ALL syntax works fine** as long as you insert more columns than just the triple proper.

Let's redefine the triple table like this:

```
create table rdf_data (id number,triple SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S);
```

And fill the new ID column in the insert, like this:

```
insert all
into rdf_data(id, triple) 
values (id, sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<rdfs:type>', '<myont:Bar>'))
into rdf_data(id, triple) 
values (id, sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFoo>', foo))
into rdf_data(id, triple) 
values (id, sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFooBar>', foobar)) 
select * from bar;

12 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
```

That operation completes successfully. I don't know why the multi-insert fails when only the triple object is inserted. We need to investigate that.

**EDIT 3: workaround: Use multiple inserts**

The other workaround is to use multiple successive INSERT ... SELECT, each one generating one of the kind of triples to produce from the input rows.

Consider this is the input table with the source for triples:

```
create table bar(id varchar(100), foo char(100), foobar char(100));
insert into bar (id, foo, foobar) values (1, 'F1', 'FB1');
insert into bar (id, foo, foobar) values (2, 'F2', 'FB2');
insert into bar (id, foo, foobar) values (3, 'F3', 'FB3');
insert into bar (id, foo, foobar) values (4, 'F4', 'FB4');
commit;
```

Here are the inserts:

```
-- Insert the "<rdfs:type>" triples
insert into rdf_data(triple) 
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<rdfs:type>', '<myont:Bar>')
from bar;

-- Insert the "<myont:hasFoo>" triples
insert into rdf_data(triple) 
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFoo>', foo)
from bar;

-- Insert the "<myont:hasFooBar>" triples
insert into rdf_data(triple) 
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFooBar>', foobar)
from bar;

commit;
```

A variant can be the more efficient:

```
insert /*+ append */ into rdf_data(triple) 
-- Insert the "<rdfs:type>" triples
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<rdfs:type>', '<myont:Bar>')
from bar
union all
-- Insert the "<myont:hasFoo>" triples
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFoo>', foo)
from bar
union all
-- Insert the "<myont:hasFooBar>" triples
select sdo_rdf_triple_s('mymodel', '<myont:'||id||'>', '<myont:hasFooBar>', foobar)
from bar;
commit;
```

Comment: As given a table with 1,000,000 tuples, I need to perform many inserts for each tuple, as such I don't think that having multiple inserts is a viable solution (I've also edited my question).

Comment: For that, just do a simple INSERT ... SELECT.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but Oracle 11g does not support `inserto into rdf_data(triple) values (...), (...) select * from bar;` as MySQL does. How am I supposed to add multiple values at once without `insert all`?

Comment: It most definitely does. What makes you think it does not ? Did you try it ? Did you get a failure ?

Comment: By looking at [Oracle11g INSERT doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604), oracle 11g does not support the syntax of the above comment. Also, the doc provides an example where multitable insert (`insert all`) is leveraged to insert into a table multiple data from the same `select` query

Comment: Ah ok. You are starting to make sense now. You actually to generate several triples from each input row. I thought you had a simple one-to-one mapping of input rows and triples, in which case the simple INSERT ... SELECT works fine. For instance: `INSERT INTO RDF_DATA SELECT SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S('MYMODEL', SUBJECT, PROPERTY, OBJECT) FROM TRIPLES;` Let me update my reply then.

Comment: The original multi-insert syntax works fine as long as you insert more than the triple column. See my edited answer.